# Process (.exe) called with "CreateProcess" crushes

Tags: c++, windows, waitforsingleobject

I have an `.exe` that on it's own it "runs" normally, no errors. I call it with `CreateProcess()` and I call `WaitForSingleObject()` to know when it has finished, and when `WaitForSingleObject()` gets called the "child" process crushes.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    STARTUPINFOA info;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;

    ZeroMemory(&info, sizeof(info));
    info.cb = sizeof(info);
    ZeroMemory(&processInfo, sizeof(processInfo));

    char path[] = "C:/.../ExeName.exe";

    if (CreateProcessA(path, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo)) {

        WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);

        CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Fail";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The called `.exe` reads from a file, does some(light I would say) calculations and heap allocation, without printing anything and then it writes the results in another file. If it can't find the files it creates them, I tried copying the file it will read from, to where the calling `.exe` is, but nothing changed.

Comment: I think you need to show more information. I don't believe in the 25+ years I have used this API that I have ever seen this behavior.

Comment: Is `[.exe path]` really a valid path to the executable? I've never seen that kind of path before.

Comment: I assume the OP did not want to give the name of the application.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, that sounds reasonable, but it'd be good to have something that looks like a real path in the question just to see that it's properly quoted etc. platinoob: Since it looks like you're running the command without arguments, what about using the first argument to ´CreateProcessA` instead of the second? You don't have to quote the first one.

Comment: *and when WaitForSingleObject() gets called the "child" process crushes.* but not because. even if not call `WaitForSingleObject` efect will be the same

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo I tried first to use the first argument but for some reason if I do it that way it can't find the `.exe`. Also, the path is valid, when it crushes it says that the `.exe` I wanted my program to run has stopped working

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, I didn't write the path manually, I found the `.exe` in File Explorer, copied the path from there and added the `.exe` name

Comment: @platinoob_ That sounds very odd. Can you show exactly how your `char path[]` is initialized or does it reveal some secrets? Change the parts that you want to hide if they contain anything sensitive.

Comment: Does the `...` part in the `path[]` contain any spaces? Are you really sure that you are starting the correct executable when using the second argument to `CreateProcessA`?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo I don't think so, in general I like to use underscores instead of spaces in names, but I will have to check, I don't have the program or the computer in front of me right now

Comment: @platinoob_ You _should_ however be able to use the first argument (and set the second to `nullptr` if you don't need to supply any arguments to the program). If you fail starting the program using the first argument, I'd say that the path is wrong somehow.

Comment: Is the called executable protected with some packer? This is a common defensive feature to check the parent process and crash if it is not explorer.exe.

Comment: @nevilad how do I check? I have done the called `.exe` with Visual Studio Community 2019, so, I think it's possible

Comment: If this exe is built from a third-party code and you didn't installed a packer, you can search it's source code for getting parent process.

Comment: @nevilad I don't use any third party code, all is mine (+ from stack overflow) and just standard C++ code

Comment: When this exe is your code, the variant with protection issues does not apply.

Comment: But when this exe is your code, why cant you just debug it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo it turns out I am an idiot, I forgot to include the `.exe` extension, now `CreateProcessA()`succeds when I use the 1st argument for the path, but the called `.exe` still crashes

Comment: @nevilad the called program on it's own it runs without crashing, the problem is when I call it through the calling program

Comment: You are asking us to debug a program we can't see. How can we possibly know why it crashes if we can't see any of its code?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't expect you to debug the program, it's just that the called program on it's own doesn't crash, it crashes when I call it through the other program, the one I am showing the code of, so I am asking if you have any suggestions as to what is the difference when I run the called program normaly vs when I call it through another program using `CreateProcessA()`, a suggestion as to what changes and might causes this crash, is there anything I need to remember when using `CreateProcessA()`? Do I use `CreateProcessA()` incorrectly?

Comment: @platinoob_ I don't see how we could tell you without knowing what that other process does. There's hundreds of small differences, any one of which might be relevant or might not. Knowing literally nothing about the program that crashes, there's absolutely no way to figure out which subtle different might affect it other than guessing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you are right, I edited the question to give a generic explanation of what the called program does, if you need any more information tell and I will edit the question

Comment: My guess is that the program doesn't have proper error checking and fails because it doesn't have permission to open the files or isn't in the expected working directory or for some other reason is unable to perform the file operations when launched this way. Do you do appropriate error checking on *all* file operations? (And see, I needed to know what the process did to form this theory.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I added some debugging messages in the called program and when I callit from another program it crashes when it's trying to read from the file, I forgot to mention that at some point it also does heap allocation

Comment: @platinoob_ A program can crash for any number of reasons. Can you make a [mre] of that program and put in your question? Without it, we're only going to be able to speculate.

Comment: @platinoob_ There you go, lack of error checking on the file operations leads to a crash. When you add proper error checking and then see what operation fails with what error, you'll have your answer.